# Joining only a part of a list of strings depends on its value in python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, for example:

```
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'list', 'of', 'strings']
```

I want to extract only some of these words and join them together only if they have quotes between them for example

so if my list was like...

```
['I', 'only', 'want', '"this', 'part"', 'of', 'the', 'list']
```

it will return "this part" Because this is the part that has quotes in between.

```
I tried using str.find("\"")
```

but it found only the first quotation mark so I couldn't really use that much, does anyone have any idea on how to do that? I appreciate all the help :))

Comment: You probably mean "quotes" and not "parenthesis"?

Comment: You mean quotes, not paranthesis

Comment: I apologize for my English, it is not quite well. I guess I do mean quotes... 
Thanks for fixing me anyways :)
(Parenthesis is the result google translate gave me lmao)

Comment: Should the answer be `"this part"` or `this part`? I.E include the quotation marks or not?

Comment: I meant for it to join all the string parts of the list that are between quotes but on the next comment someone showed me a better way of returning a list of all joined strings that are between quotes and it solves what I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following pattern with `re.findall`:

```
l = ['I', 'only', 'want', '"this', 'part"', 'of', 'the', 'list', '"another', 'example"']

re.findall(r'\"(.*?)\"', ' '.join(l))
# ['this part', 'another example']
```

Answer (score 1):

`str` has method `rfind` which return index of last occurence (or `-1` if not found), so you might do:

```
elements = ['I', 'only', 'want', '"this', 'part"', 'of', 'the', 'list']
txt = ' '.join(elements)
part = txt[txt.find('"')+1:txt.rfind('"')]
print(part)  # this part
```

`+1` is required due to inclusive-exclusive nature of slicing in Python.